# 0% Texture cache hit rate using CUDA surfaces

Tags: caching, memory, cuda, textures, surface

From what I understand from the CUDA programming guide, whether I access using textures or surfaces, reads are routed through the texture cache. However, when I run the Memory experiments on NSIGHT, it says that the texture cache hit rate is 0%, whereas using textures got me a 99% hit rate using the same kernel.

The kernel is for a mini-census transform, where the pixels accessed are:

```
x x r x x

x x r x x

r x o x r

x x r x x

x x r x x
```

Where "r" stands for the pixels around the anchor pixel "o" which are read.

Here is the kernel and the stub:

```
__global__ void census_transform_kernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t input, cudaSurfaceObject_t output, int width, int height){
    //16 x 16 threads
    int row_to_access = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col_to_access = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (row_to_access < height && col_to_access < width){
        unsigned char ref = surf2Dread<unsigned char>(input, col_to_access, row_to_access, cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
        unsigned char sum = 
            ((surf2Dread<unsigned char>(input, col_to_access, row_to_access - 2, cudaBoundaryModeZero) > ref) << 5) +
            ((surf2Dread<unsigned char>(input, col_to_access, row_to_access - 1, cudaBoundaryModeZero) > ref) << 4) +
            ((surf2Dread<unsigned char>(input, col_to_access - 2, row_to_access, cudaBoundaryModeZero) > ref) << 3) +
            ((surf2Dread<unsigned char>(input, col_to_access + 2, row_to_access, cudaBoundaryModeZero) > ref) << 2) +
            ((surf2Dread<unsigned char>(input, col_to_access, row_to_access + 1, cudaBoundaryModeZero) > ref) << 1) +
            ((surf2Dread<unsigned char>(input, col_to_access, row_to_access + 2, cudaBoundaryModeZero) > ref));

        surf2Dwrite(sum, output, col_to_access, row_to_access, cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
    }
}

void census_transform(cudaSurfaceObject_t input, cudaSurfaceObject_t output, int width, int height){
    dim3 threads(16, 16);
    dim3 blocks(DIVIDE_UP(width, threads.x), DIVIDE_UP(width, threads.y));

    census_transform_kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(input, output, width, height);
    SAFE_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), "Census transform failed.");
}


int main(){
  cv::Mat left_im = cv::imread("im.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    cudaArray *d_left_array;
    cudaArray *d_right_array;

  cudaChannelFormatDesc left_array_channel_desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<unsigned char>(); 
  cudaMallocArray(&d_left_array, &left_array_channel_desc, width * sizeof(unsigned char), height, cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore);

  cudaChannelFormatDesc left_census_array_channel_desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<unsigned char>();  
  cudaMallocArray(&d_left_census_array, &left_census_array_channel_desc, width * sizeof(unsigned char), height, cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore);

  cudaResourceDesc left_array_resc; 
  memset(&left_array_resc, 0, sizeof(left_array_resc));
  cudaResourceDesc left_census_array_resc; 
  memset(&left_census_array_resc, 0, sizeof(left_census_array_resc));

  left_array_resc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray; 
  left_array_resc.res.array.array = d_left_array;
  left_census_array_resc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray; 
  left_census_array_resc.res.array.array = d_left_census_array;

  cudaSurfaceObject_t left_array_tex = 0; 
  cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&left_array_tex, &left_array_resc);
  cudaSurfaceObject_tleft_census_array_tex = 0; 
  cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&left_census_array_tex, &left_census_array_resc);
  
  cudaMemcpyToArray(d_left_array, 0, 0, left_im.data, height * width * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    census_transform(left_array_tex, left_census_array_tex, width, height);
    
    return 0;
}
```